# Error al mostrar valores con Currency en Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Estoy cargando valores los cuales llegan como `string` y al momento de agregarlos a la propiedad los combierto anteponiendo el simbolo **`+`** y al  mostrarlos les agrego un `pipe` `currency` para que este le ponga el símbolo **`$`** y el punto separador de miles.

Funciona perfecto pero en algunas ocaciones, cuando realizo la carga de los valores aparece las letras **`PS`**.

Agrego el código:

Declaración de la variable en el **modelo**:

```
export class NaturalesAllModel {
   TotalIngresos: number;
}
```

La información la cargo en el **component** de la siguiente manera:

```
this.naturalesAllModel.TotalIngresos = (+this.naturalesAllModel.Salario + +this.naturalesAllModel.Comisiones + +this.naturalesAllModel.Arriendos +  +this.naturalesAllModel.OtrosIngresos);
```

En la **vista** los muestro de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 FormatoNaturalesRight">
   <label class="letraGrande">${{naturalesAllModel.TotalIngresos | currency:'':'' : '1.0'}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Funciona perfecto, muestra la informacion de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en ocaciones muestra los valores así, si ven la imagen carga un **PS**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me genera ningún error solo aparecen , cuando recargo la pagina vuelven a aparecer los valores como son.

Alguien me podría decir el por que pasa esto y como solucionarlo ,

De ante mano Gracias.

Comment: no te aparece nada en consola?

Comment: Probaste de pronto algún otro formato como `currency:'':symbol: '1.0-2'`?

Comment: No, hice el debug y no aparece nada

Comment: @jecorrales voy a probar agregando este `currency` , pero la dificultad es que se presenta esporádica mente no siempre.

Comment: @jecorrales, agrega el `currency` como me dijiste pero al mostrar los valores agrega un `USD` al inicio y no puede ser así ya que en nuestro país no se utiliza esa unidad.

Comment: Extraño, no debería, que versión de Angular estás usando? De hecho puedes mirar este ejemplo en [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/suma-total)

Comment: Estoy utilizando `Angular 8` , Mira: `"@angular/animations": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.2",`

Comment: ¿No te funcionó con la nueva segudilla? y de pronto probaste sin aplicar el formato `currency` para ver si es del formato o algún dato que se esté generando incorrectamente y por ende el filtro no se puede aplicar?lo que también me lleva a pensar, ¿de donde estás obteniendo los datos?

Comment: ¿de donde estás obteniendo los datos?: Te respondo son datos obtenidos de SQL , normal no tengi ningun problema al obtenerlos y se muestran normal, solo que a veces aparece este error como lo puse en la pregunta

Comment: Es posible que sea debido al intentar convertir las cadenas a numeros usando el "+". Yo probaria a usar parseInt o parseFloat. Asi, si no se puede convertir a numero, al menos te da la excepcion y puedes debugear.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar convirtiendo con el Parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta dependencia te permite trabajar los valores de los input para su presentacion [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

```
<input type='text' suffix=" $" mask="0000" >
```

Solo lo he probado con tag input no se si trabaja sobre otros tag pero en si, solo es una directiva. `@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[brmasker]'
})` por lo que supongo que puede ser usado en otros tag con entradas de datos.
[github](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/blob/develop/src/app/ngx-mask/mask.directive.ts)